# Invalid type in JSON write in Swift Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2, alamofire

I am having issues sending my parameters over Alamofire.  This is the JSON that the server expects:

```
{
“users”:[{“_id”:”1234567”}, {“_id”:”665543”}]
}
```

Now, in my Swift code, this is how I’m trying to build out the above object:

```
let parameters = [“users” : users]
return sendRequest(.PUT, url: “example.com", parameters: parameters)
```

where users is an array. Here is more info on what users is (I have taken out some of the other inherits to simplify):

```
class User : MyBase, CustomStringConvertible {
  var name: String

  var description : String {
     get{
          return ["_id" : self._id!].description
     }
 }
}

class MyBase {
  var _id: String?
}
```

If I do a `debugPrint(users)`, this is what I get:

```
[“users”: [["_id": "1234567"], ["_id": "665543"]]]
```

And here’s the sendRequest method that does the Alamofire stuff:

```
static func sendRequest(method: Alamofire.Method, url: String, parameters: [String: AnyObject]?) {
        Alamofire.request(method, url, parameters: parameters as! [String: [User]], encoding: .JSON)
            .validate()
            .responseObject { (response: Response<User, NSError>) in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success(let value):
                    // do something
                case .Failure(let error):
                    // do something else
                }
        }
    }
```

And the error it throws on the Alamofire.request line is this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (MyApp.User)’
```

Ultimately, what I have is an array of user objects, and I need to send that to my server in the JSON format mentioned above. Being new to Swift, I’ve been struggling trying to figure this out, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be in your debugPrint(users). What you're sending to the server is an optional type. You need to send the String

so where you have self._id change that to self._id!

Comment: I did that and debugPrint now gives this: [“users”: [["_id": "1234567"], ["_id": "665543"]]]. But unfortunately, I still get the same error.

Comment: Okay, so you're sending an array and it's saying invalid type in JSON write, so it could be expecting JSON. Have you tried something like:

let json_data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(users, options: nil, error: nil)

?

Comment: That line gives me an error "Extra argument 'error' in call"

Comment: Not sure if the error is needed TBH. I was eye balling. I know when pulling JSON with Alamofire you'll use it with just the options. Try eliminating it so that your arguments are just users and options:nil